# Sorting a list of cards by face value

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, append

my input is:

```
cards = ['Jack', 8, 2, 6, 'King', 5, 3, 'Queen']
```

and the expected output is `[2,3,5,6,8,'Jack','Queen','King']` but generic method mean always number comes first and then alphabets sequences comes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577). You can't just dump your problem statement here and expect us to do it for you. It's also a good idea to take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and [ask].

Comment: And there is no need to add "Q:" to your title. You clicked the "Ask Question" button on a question and answer site. We know you have a question. Removing "Q:" gives an error that a question with that title already exists—that should be a strong clue that you should look at that existing question and, if its answers don't help, refine this question so it is meaningfully different.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) with a helper dictionary and a [custom key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions):

```
cards = ['Jack', 8, 2, 6, 'King', 5, 3, 'Queen'] 

# add other values (e.g. "Ace" if needed)
heads = {'Jack': 11, 'Queen': 12, 'King': 13} 

sorted(cards, key=lambda x: heads.get(x, x))
```

output: `[2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']`

The `key` is applied to the values before sorting, thus `lambda x: heads.get(x,x)` will get you either the value in `heads` if the key is present or return the value itself is the key is absent, then this is equivalent to sorting `[11, 8, 2, 6, 13, 5, 3, 12]`

Comment: Probably also want to put `'Ace'` in there, and depending on the game you would want it as the start or end.

Comment: @flakes yes of course, but I leave it to OP to customize ;)